# Laravel scout algolia geosearch

Tags: php, laravel, search, algolia

I'm trying to make a request to my algolia index with geoSearch parameters. My query is working until I add the whereDate and all the where parameters after the search.

Can you please tell me how to do the request properly ?

Thanks

```
return Event::search('', function ($algolia, $query, $options) use ($lat, $lng, $radius){
            $location = [
              'aroundLatLng' => $lat.','.$lng,
              'aroundRadius' => $radius * 1000,
            ];

            $options = array_merge($options, $location);

            return $algolia->search($query, $options);
        })->whereDate('start_at', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($day))->where('end_at', '>=',
          \Carbon\Carbon::parse($day))->orWhere('start_at', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($day))->where('end_at',
          '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($day))->orderBy('events.start_at')->orderBy('events.start_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to add the where statement in Algolia too.
Laravel Scout only handle simple where clauses (only = to a numeric).

```
    return Event::search('', function ($algolia, $query, $options) use ($lat, $lng, $radius){
        $custom = [
          'aroundLatLng' => $lat.','.$lng,
          'aroundRadius' => $radius * 1000,
          'filters' => 'start_at>12 AND end_at<16',
        ];

        $options = array_merge($options, $custom);

        return $algolia->search($query, $options);
    })->get();
```

You can find the documentation related to filters here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/